# Should "persistent" field appear in serialized PanacheEntity?

Tags: orm, jackson, quarkus

I am building a simple Jaxrs api in quarkus.  When I call my index method it looks like jackson serializes the objects with the `persistent` field, that it gets from the `PanacheEntityBase`.

Example:

```
[
    {
        "persistent": true,
        "id": 1,
        "createdAt": "2019-03-18",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-18"
    },
    {
        "persistent": true,
        "id": 2,
        "createdAt": "2019-03-18",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-18"
    }
]
```

The `persistent` field isn't saved to the database, but it shows up in the response.  I have looked into using `@jsonIgnore` and jackson mixins, but I would rather not have to do this, especially if this is just a configuration issue.  I am curious if Panache should be doing this, or if anyone else is having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when we use `3-rd party libraries` as returned data type and provide it to `Jackson` serialisation process. `PanacheEntity` extends [PanacheEntityBase](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/panache/hibernate-orm-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheEntityBase.java) which contains `isPersistent` method which is treated by `Jackson` like a `POJO` `getter` method.

```
public boolean isPersistent() {
    return JpaOperations.isPersistent(this);
}
```

`Jackson` automatically takes all `get*` and `is*` methods and try to serialise it and include to result `JSON`. There is no way to configure it on `quarkus` level. Your solution with [`JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) and `MixIn` feature is good approach.

Comment: Awesome.  This confirms my suspicions.  Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

With Json-B add in your entity :

```
@JsonbTransient
public boolean isPersistent() {
    return super.isPersistent();
}
```